# How do I check for a status bit on a running process?

Tags: server, bash, apache2, php

OK, here's my dilemma, I'm running headless Ubuntu server 18.04.3 LTS on a Dell PowerEdge T710 server, and I'm writing a bash script so that I can easily change the Apache PHP Mod versions without having to keep manually using:-

```
a2dismod php<version>
a2enmod php<version>
systemctl restart apache2
```

The beginning of the script uses an if condition to check if the user is logged in as a user account or a root account using the status bit of UID, ie:-

```
if ((UID)); then
something here
elif ((!UID)); then
something here
fi
```

using ((UID)) to check if the bit is true and using ((!UID) to check if the bit is false, but here's the problem, I want to add a little bit more checking to make sure apache is actually in a running state, I would rather use boolean true or false than to use something like:-

```
systemctl status apache2
```

which gives a lot of output.  Is there a status bit for apache? Then I can do a check to make sure apache is actually running before continuing the phpmod version change.

This is the script I have so far: https://pastebin.com/HyCjbn59

IT not only needs the checking for apache running, but also a check for the various apache PHP modules to make sure they are actually installed before attempting to enable the correct module, and if not, then the script would execute:-

```
apt install libapache2-mod-php<version>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `is-active` unit command of `systemctl` which “[r]eturns an exit code 0 if at least one [unit] is active, or non-zero otherwise”:

```
if systemctl is-active --quiet apache2; then
  echo running
else
  echo not running
fi
```

If you’d rather use a parameter there’s `$?` holding the exit code of the last command, you can simply test for it being `0`:

```
systemctl is-active --quiet apache2
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo running
else
  echo not running
fi
```

#### Further reading

- [The “proper” way to test if a service is running in a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/396630/246819)
- [`man systemctl`/COMMANDS](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#is-active%20PATTERN%E2%80%A6)

Answer (score 1):

Defining own exit codes still uses the same logic as @Dessert describes in his answer.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

systemctl is-active -q apache2 && status=TRUE || status=FALSE

case $status in
  TRUE)
    echo do something ;;
  FALSE)
    echo do sothing else ;;
esac
```

Comment: Note that this will set `status=FALSE` if `systemctl` fails for any reason as well – `a && b || c` is *not* the same as `if a; then b; else c; fi`!