# why is if statement working on terminal but not as script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, systemd, services

I am trying to make a script that checks if a service is running (sickchill in this case) and if not start it with systemctl.

My code is working as intended if I execute it from the terminal, but when I try it from a bash script, it acts if the service is already running eventhough it is not running...

I have no idea why this is as the code it still the same.

Any ideas on why this is?

My shell commands and results:

```
 user@plex-webserver  § ~  sudo /opt/scripts/check-sickchill-service

sickchill.service is running

 user@plex-webserver  § ~  sudo systemctl status sickchill.service

● sickchill.service - SickChill Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sickchill.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2020-09-19 08:11:31 UTC; 32s ago
    Process: 636533 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /opt/sickchill/SickChill.py -q --daemon --nolaunch --datadir=/opt/sickchill (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 19 08:10:08 plex-webserver systemd[1]: Starting SickChill Daemon...
Sep 19 08:10:10 plex-webserver systemd[1]: Started SickChill Daemon.
Sep 19 08:10:10 plex-webserver python3[636549]: /opt/sickchill/sickchill/locale
Sep 19 08:10:10 plex-webserver python3[636549]: /opt/sickchill/sickchill/locale
Sep 19 08:10:10 plex-webserver python3[636549]: /opt/sickchill/sickchill/locale
Sep 19 08:11:20 plex-webserver systemd[1]: Stopping SickChill Daemon...
Sep 19 08:11:31 plex-webserver systemd[1]: sickchill.service: Succeeded.
Sep 19 08:11:31 plex-webserver systemd[1]: Stopped SickChill Daemon.

 user@plex-webserver  § ~  if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE | wc -l) > 0 ))
then
        echo "$SERVICE is running"
else
        systemctl start $SERVICE
        echo "restarted $SERVICE"
fi
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to start 'sickchill.service'.
Authenticating as: Username (user)
Password:
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
restarted sickchill
```

My script (check-sickchill-service):

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVICE=sickchill.service

if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE | wc -l) > 0 ))
then
        echo "$SERVICE is running"
else
        systemctl start $SERVICE
        echo "restarted $SERVICE"
fi
```

Comment: Because `.` in a regular expression matches any character, `grep sickchill.service` will match the name of your script, `check-sickchill-service`. FYI you should use `pgrep` instead of piping `ps` though multiple greps

Comment: Could it be that the name of the script is `check-sickchill-service` so possibly when you grep for `sickchill-service` it returns a result for `check-sickchill-service`? Have you tried grepping for something more specific or possibly adding `grep -v check-sickchill-service`?

Comment: ... or probably better, use `systemctl is-active` as shown here: [How do I check for a status bit on a running process?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1199070/178692)

Comment: @steeldriver for some reason, pgrep is returning nothing on sickchill while the status says it is running. but you are right, it does match the script name... doing another grep -v makes it work like it should (like mchid suggested) but that seems a bit stupid (already thought using 2 greps was stupid and was thinking of using awk instead...

Comment: @steeldriver thanks! that did fix the issue and it is way cleaner!